# jQuery $.get call to method in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a .csHtml page. The page is populated by calling a method in the contoller using Jquery $.get. The method in the controller makes a database call and returns a partial view. The partial view is rendered inside a DIV tag.

The data is being displayed real time. Now when I hit ctrl + f5, the page refreshes, but it still shows the same data. I put a breakpoint in the controller method and realized that the method in controller is not being called.

The first time the method is being called when I hit F5 and run in Visual Studio. The second time when I refresh the data is not being refreshed.

If I have to see any changes being displayed in the database, I need to restart the visual studio.

Any clue on what could be happenning?? Below is the snippet of code.

```
// Our onReady actions;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#RateTab').click(function () {
        getRates();
    });
});

function getRates() {
    var URL = "home/Rates";

    $.get(URL, function (data) {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $("#rates").html(data);

        //Initialize();
    });
}
```

Any ideas and suggestions on what could be happenning ??

Comment: Can we see the controller code that is being called by the Ajax call?

Comment: @elkdanger: I put the break point in the beginning of the controller method and see and it doesnt hit the method. However the variable data gets populated with the old data.

Comment: No `[OutputCache]` enabled on the controller, correct?

Comment: @DotNetUser Yes you said that in your post. I was just trying to see if you'd added any caching attributes, as asked by Brad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a cache that is enabled. You can control cache by using the `$.ajax` method. Try to rewrite it like that :

```
$.ajax({
   url : URL,
   type : 'GET',
   cache : false,
   success : function (data) { 
            $('#loading').hide(); 
            $("#rates").html(data);}
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was writing, you can typically test it by inspecting the response in the dev tools of whatever browser you are using, which typically still shows the correct response and then the html is just updated with the cached data.

Comment: @Thomas Jaskula, the caching was enabled and that's what caused the problem. Thanks!